# recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2, okhttp

I am trying to Delete some medias from my mobile application using `retrofit2` REST client.

```
@HTTP(method = "DELETE",path="/api/v1/media/{username}/{accesstoken}", hasBody = true)
Call<MyResponse> deleteArchiveMedia(@Path("username") String username, @Path("accesstoken") String token  ,
                                    @Body DeleteMedia deleteMedia);
```

This is the call for delete.

DeleteMedia is a class which contains 2 array lists, one is for channelId and other for Mediaid's

Delete is working when delete a few medias (less than 100),but while delete more than 100 medias it will return an error like:

```
recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
```

Why this is happening only when I am trying to delete large amount of size medias?

Is there any limit for `retroffit2` body length?

Please help me......

class for getting retrofit

```
public class DeleteModule {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.getBaseURL())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).client(okHttpClient)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Incomplete. How are you *using* the `Retrofit`? Why are you building a new client even when you aren't going to use it?